# Does a package 'see' itself in __init__.py?

Tags: python, python-import, nameerror, python-packaging

I have a flask app with the root folder called `project_folder`.

A code snippet from the `__init__.py` file of this `project_folder` package:

```
@jwt.token_in_blacklist_loader
def check_if_token_in_blacklist(decrypted_token):
    jti = decrypted_token['jti']
    return project_folder.Model.RevokedTokenModel.is_jti_blacklisted(jti)

from project_folder.Controller.root import root
from project_folder.Controller import auth_controller
from project_folder.Controller import item_controller
```

Now the interesting thing is, that the `project_folder` package naturally has other smaller packages itself, which I'm importing to use them (for REST resources in this example). These are the last 3 lines, nothing throws an error so far.

But, if you take a look at the annotated function (in this example it always runs before some kind of JWT Token is being used), I am returning some inner package's function. Now when the logic truly runs this part the code breaks:

```
PROJECT_ROUTE\project_folder\__init__.py", line 38, in check_if_token_in_blacklist
    return project_folder.Model.RevokedTokenModel.is_jti_blacklisted(jti)
NameError: name 'project_folder' is not defined
```

After thinking about it, it seems understandable. Importing from `project_folder` does import from the `__init__.py` file of the package, which is the actual file the interpreter currently is. So removing the package name prefix form the

```
return project_folder.Model.RevokedTokenModel.is_jti_blacklisted(jti)
```

to

```
return Model.RevokedTokenModel.is_jti_blacklisted(jti)
```

does not throw an error anymore.

The question is: Why is it only a problem inside the callback function and not with the last 3 imports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with circular imports in python. Circular import is a form of circular dependency, created at the module import level.

How it works:

When you launch your application, python keeps a register (a kind of table) in which it records all the imported modules. When you call somewhere in your code a module, python will see in its registry if it has already been registered and loads it from there. You can access this registry via `sys.module`, which is actually a `dictionary` containing all the modules that have been imported since Python was started.

Example of use:

```
>>> import sys
>>> print('\n'.join(sys.modules.keys()))
```

So, since Python is an interpreted language, reading and execution of code is done line by line from top to bottom.

In your code, you put your imports at the bottom of your `__init__.py` file.

While browsing it, when python arrives at the line `return project_folder.Model.RevokedTokenModel.is_jti_blacklisted(jti)`, it will look if the module exists in its register. Which is clearly not yet the case. That's why he raises an `NameError: name 'project_folder' is not defined` exception.

Comment: Thank you for the clear response! So if I understand you correctly, I can't even use a single function from a clearly 'visible' route without importing the modul or at least the file which contains it?

Comment: As far as I know, it's impossible. But if you want to avoid importing a module, you just have to move your function in the file in which you need it.